# Creating an asynchronous method that contains a linq query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 2.2 web app that uses Entity Framework.

In the project, I have this controller that uses Linq to join two tables, and then uses Select to create a node model, like this:

```
    [HttpGet("GameDownloadLinks/{libraryId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GameDownloadLinks>>> GetGameLinksForlibraryAsync(Guid libraryID)
    {
        var libraryGameLinks =  (from gk in _context.GameLinks
                                   join gl in _context.GameList on gk.GameId equals gl.GameId
                                   where gl.libraryId == libraryId
                                   select new GameDownloadLinks
                                   {
                                       LibraryId = gl.libraryId,
                                       LinkText = gk.LinkText,
                                       Price = gk.Price,
                                       GameId = gl.GameId
                                   }).ToList();

        var asyncGameDownloadLinks = await Task.WhenAll(libraryGameLinks).toListAsync();
        return asyncGameDownloadLinks;
    }
```

I'm trying to make this method asynchronous, but I get this error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.GameDownloadLinks>'  to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
```

Some of the answers I found for similar questions indicated this is most likely due to a missing async keyword in the method declaration, but I have included that in mine.

Is there anyway to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: .ToListAsync instead of .ToList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```cs
  [HttpGet("GameDownloadLinks/{libraryId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GameDownloadLinks>>> GetGameLinksForlibraryAsync(Guid libraryID)
    {
        var libraryGameLinks = await (from gk in _context.GameLinks
                                   join gl in _context.GameList on gk.GameId equals gl.GameId
                                   where gl.libraryId == libraryId
                                   select new GameDownloadLinks
                                   {
                                       LibraryId = gl.libraryId,
                                       LinkText = gk.LinkText,
                                       Price = gk.Price,
                                       GameId = gl.GameId
                                   }).ToListAsync();

       // var asyncGameDownloadLinks = await Task.WhenAll(libraryGameLinks).toListAsync();
        return libraryGameLinks ;
    }
```